# React Util js file not working with absolute path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, export, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app. No eject.

I need help figuring out why this doesn't work.

```
import { capitalizeFirst } from 'util/util.js'; //This one doesn't work

import AdminInput from 'components/AdminInput/AdminInput.jsx';

console.log(capitalizeFirst); // returns undefined
```

and my .env

```
NODE_PATH=src/
```

and my util.js

```
export function capitalizeFirst(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

The other components work as expected. Using the function will also result in "TypeError: _util.capitalizeFirst is not a function" or something like that.

However, if I use

```
import { capitalizeFirst } from '../../util/util.js';
```

it will print the correct function instead.

I don't understand why the js file doesn't work but the React Components work with an absolute path?

[image: Util is in source...]

Comment: Are you sure the `util` directory is directly in your `src` directory?

Comment: 100% sure. So it doesn't seem to have anything to do with that.

Comment: @Tholle I added a picture of the folder structure so it's possible to see where util is.

Answer (score 0):

It resolves to [util/util](https://github.com/browserify/node-util/blob/master/util.js) from `node_modules`